# remove everything after first occurence of a pattern regex gsub R

Tags: r, regex

This might be super easy but I still cannot find the answer. I would like to remove everything before the first "que" in my string:

What I am doing:

```
v <- c("blabla que 1", "blabla que eu Boqueirão que ")
gsub(".*que", "", v)
# [1] " 1"   "irão"
```

What I want is "1" e "eu Boqueirão que ". When I try `.*^que` it does make any effect. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `sub(".*?(que)", "\\1", x)` or `sub(".*?que", "", x)`

Comment: Or, `sub(".*?que\\s*", "", v)`

Comment: This is not so straight-forward here if you need to also remove all the whitespaces after `que`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on Jet's answer you can also use `stringr::extract`

```
v <- c("blabla que 1", "blabla que eu Boqueirão que ")
stringr::str_extract(v, '(?<=que ).+')
```

Output

```
[1] "1"                 "eu Boqueirão que "
```

To comment on Wiktor S's answer you want `sub` instead of `gsub` as `sub` replaces the first instance but `gsub` finds all or *globally* replaces

Answer (score 4):

To remove all up to and including the first occurrence of a pattern use

```
sub(".*?que", "", v)
[1] " 1"                 " eu Boqueirao que "
```

If you also need to remove any 0+ whitespace after use

```
sub(".*?que\\s*", "", v, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "1"                 "eu Boqueirao que "
```

Note that `perl=TRUE` is important here as the `.*?que\s*` TRE regex disables greediness with the first non-greedy quantifier `*?` on the current level, and `\s*` acts as a non-greedy pattern, and non-greedy patterns at the end of a regex never match any strings.

*BONUS*: Just in case you want to remove all text up to the first occurrence of a pattern *excluding this pattern* wrap the part you need to keep with capturing parentheses and use `\1` in the replacement pattern:

```
sub(".*?(que)", "\\1", v)
## => [1] "que 1"                 "que eu Boqueirao que "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringr::str_match`

```
v <- c("blabla que 1", "blabla que eu Boqueirão que ")
stringr::str_match(v, 'que(.*)')[,2]
```

Output:

```
[1] " 1"                 " eu Boqueirão que "
```